# How do you customize the Picker element in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a simple form, and I need a segmented picker. But I can't get the text to wrap and have the longest text elements go on several lines.

```
Text("QQQ")
Picker("QQQ", selection: pBody) {
   ForEach(0..<array.count) { index in
     Text(array[index]).tag(index)
   }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your are after, but if you want a segmented picker, try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var array = ["aaa","bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhhhhhh", "iiiiiii", "jjjjjjjjjjjjjj", "kkkkk", "lllll", "mmmmmmmm","nnn","ooooooooo","ppppp"]
@State var pBody = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("QQQ")
        ScrollView (.horizontal) {
            Picker("QQQ", selection: $pBody) {
                ForEach(0..<array.count) { index in
                    Text(self.array[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())  // <--- segmented picker
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding text wrapping.  You cannot wrap text in a picker segment. That control is not available to us. You would need to build a custom one.